# no provisioned ios device is connected

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, sdk, ios-4.2

i get the message as seen in the title if i try to run my app on the device. i investigated that i have the ios 4.2.1 (8C148) on my device. whats confusing me is the fact that in xcode i only can choose the target(ios deployment target) to be 4.2 and the system-profiler->software->developer shows me "Version:  3.2 (10M2423)"(witch i think is the latest) but under SDKs i only see iPhone OS: 4.2(8C134) and iPhone Simulator:  and 4.2(8C134)

could this be the reason for this error, that the device is "newer" than my sdk?

Comment: is the device shown in the xcode organizer?

Comment: yes and with a green "all things are right" indicator ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magically the problem appears to be gone. as i turn one's back on that problem and simply developed for simulator, today its simply working ... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the 4.2 sdk from Apple's website. Looks like you only have the 3.2 one installed properly on your machine, you might have to redownload and reinstall.

Check out the wikipedia page for ios version numbers to confirm you're running the correct one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history

Comment: but 10M2423 points to be the latest one!? i actually installed the sdk and xcode i downloaded a few days ago.